# simple for loop over a distinctList in Power Query for an API request

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have to admit my confidence has taken a hit with this one.

I have a single list which i extrapolate from a table with the `List.Distinct` function.

I have an API I need to call but needs to take an ID which will come from the `List.Distinct` output.

so my question is how can I loop over my `distinct_list` and feed that as a parameter into my query in the api call.

in Pseudo code this would be:

```
distinct_table = unique(table[id])
empty_list = []
for each_id in distinct_table[List]:
    j = JsonDocument("www.apicall.com?peopleid=each_id")
    empty_list.append(j)
```

Code so far.

```
let
    distinct_list = List.Distinct(Projects[project_id])

    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://api.random.com",
                                                    [
                                                       RelativePath="/v3/logged-tasks",
                                                       Headers = [mytoken],
                                                       query = [
                                                       person_id = (each row from distinct_list)],
   #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)





in 
    Source
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend making the API call its own function.

For example, this function I've named `API` returns text for a given number:

```
(n as number) as text =>
let
    Source = Text.FromBinary(Web.Contents("http://numbersapi.com/"&Text.From(n)&"/math"))
in
    Source
```

Now we can call this function in other queries. For example:

```
let
    distinct_list = {3,6,12},
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(distinct_list, Splitter.SplitByNothing()),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Converted to Table", "API", each API([Column1]))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Here's what this looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

If you can transform instead of adding a column if you prefer:

```
Table.TransformColumns(#"Converted to Table", {{"Column1", each API(_), type text}})
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alexis, when I try to save my query I get the following error `Formula.Firewall: Query 'LoggedTasks' (step 'Added Custom') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.`

Comment: That's an annoying privacy level thing. I usually have my settings ignore privacy level. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/desktop-privacy-levels

Comment: Legend, I just had to change my type to `List` and the rest sorted it self out, thanks for your help !